# C++ Type-safe detection of the offset of a structure

Tags: c++

I'm playing a bit with the C++ syntax to figure out a generalized way to keep track of an offset within a class, sort of like `offsetof`, but in a type-safe way and without `#define`s

I know that a template class can be template-parametrized with *fields*, besides types and constants. So I came out with this prototype:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename class_type, typename field_type>
struct offsetter
{
    offsetter(const char* name, field_type class_type::*field)
        : name(name)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%zu\n", field);
    }

    const char* const name;
};

struct some_struct
{
    float avg;
    int min;
    int max;
    struct internal
    {
        unsigned flag;
        int x;
    } test;
    char* name;
};

int main()
{
    offsetter<some_struct, float>("%h", &some_struct::avg);
    offsetter<some_struct, int>("%h", &some_struct::min);
    offsetter<some_struct, char*>("%h", &some_struct::name);
    offsetter<some_struct, some_struct::internal>("x", &some_struct::test);

    return 0;
}
```

This code is actually able to print the field offset, but I'm not really sure on what I'm doing here. Indeed it feels utterly wrong to reference `field` without referring to an instance (`foo.*field`).

But it does the job: it prints the offset. My guess is that I'm hitting on some loophole though, since for instance I can't assign `size_t offset = field`.

I figured out I probably want something like this:

```
size_t offset = (&(std::declval<class_type>().*field) - &(std::declval<class_type>()))
```

Which however wont' work as I can't take the address of an xvalue:

```
taking address of xvalue (rvalue reference)
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: are you looking for [`offsetof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof)?

Comment: @Mgetz offsetof is indeed a macro, although standard. I was playfully trying to do that template-style.

Comment: When it comes to things like this I would suggest using the standard, different compilers may do things differently and this is guaranteed to work insofar as the object is standard layout. That said you could wrap it in a template.

Comment: @Mgetz that shouldn't stop you from experimenting and pushing the limits. Ok, don't use this in a production env, but the question is till valid.

Comment: Following how, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offsetof), `offsetof` is sometimes implemented, you could do something like `(size_t) &(((class_type*) nullptr)->*field_type)`, although it's dangerously close to UB.

Comment: @bolov no this little thing called undefined behavior usually stops me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there isn't a standard way of doing this. Even the standard `offsetof` is defined only for standard layout types.

What you are doing is UB. You are using the wrong specifier `zu`. There isn't much you can do with a member pointer. You can't even do pointer arithmetics on them, you can't convert to `char*` nor to an integer type.

Also if your assumption is that a member pointer is just an integer representing the offset from the beginning of the structure that is false, not only in theory, but also in practice. Having multiple inheritance and virtual inheritance made sure of that.

Comment: By UB you mean Undefined Behaviour, I guess?